# How to encrypt FireDAC connection to use TLS/SSL in Delphi?

Tags: oracle, delphi, ssl, tls1.2, firedac

How do I configure TFDConnection of FireDAC to use TLS/SSL encryption?

I want to encrypt the connection to the Oracle database.
I use Delphi 10.3 and Oracle thin client in win 10.

Comment: What did you try? I am almost certain the Oracle Instant Client is able to connect using TLS. Check your connection string. Did you try to follow the tutoralis like https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/configure-tcpip-with-ssl-and-tls-for-database-connections